# Linking libs with make/g++ under ubuntu

Tags: g++, makefile, libs

lets say my makefile looks like this:

```
CXX = g++

OGLLIBS = -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32

projname : projname.o
    ${CXX} -o projname $< ${OGLLIBS}
```

Then in which directory does g++ look for the libraries? I was assuming . but if I put the libs there it still complains about not finding them (`*.lib` is the correct file or does unix use another ending?!)

Answer (score 0):

1. Folders
   unix uses the folders /lib (for system lib) and /usr/lib
   your own libraries or newly installed should be in /usr/local/lib but you need to add "-I/usr/local/lib" as compiler flag.
2. file ending
   is .so for shared libs basicly
3. looking for libs
   your can tell your compiler to add other directories to look for libs by setting a variable called LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root-to-my-libs